# Using a HEX value from a color picker for three.js as a string

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js

So I have a color picker, which outputs colors in this format: **FFA6A6**. It is a plugin from jscolor.com. I am using three.js to change the color of something live when I change it with the color picker. However, three.js takes 0xFFA6A6, not just that. On top of that, I can not concatenate 0x to FFA6A6, which would make it a string. Also, it outputs colors as a string, and I cannot seem to remove it from being a string

ex:"FFA6A6" to FFA6A6

How would I change **FFA6A6** to something that can be recognized as a three.js color? This is what I have:

```
function updateNoseColor(){
    scene.remove(nose);
    var geometry = new THREE.ConeGeometry( .4, 1, 32 );

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: document.getElementById("nosecolor").value} );
    //three.js cannot take a string as a value, so im not sure what to do
    var nose = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add(nose);
}
```

Thank you for your time, there is probably an extremely simple solution that I do not know of. Again, the problem is removing the quotes, and adding it to `0x`
Thanks!

**EDIT**: I have tried converting to a decimal with ParseInt, it is not accepted by three.js

Comment: You can use `parseInt`, just make sure you include the `0x` in front. `0xFFF === parseInt('0xFFF')` will evaluate to true.

Comment: @DrewSnow That doesn't work either

Comment: It returns this when I find it in console: Color {r: 0.4196078431372549, g: 1, b: 0.7529411764705882}

Comment: @UnityDude You added the JavaScript code in a pastebin. Could you add your HTML code too? Maybe using https://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kpws7zfc/

Comment: @UnityDude The code doesn't run, maybe due to incorrect script imports. Could you check that it runs as it's running on your computer. Then, we can try to debug it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Color` class ([reference](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Color)) from three.js. For example:

```js
var color = new THREE.Color("#FFA6A6"); // "FFA6A6" won't work!
color.getHex(); // 0xFFA6A6
```

That said, **replace your following code** with the given code:

```js
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: document.getElementById("nosecolor").value} );
```

with

```js
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: new Color(document.getElementById("nosecolor").value)} );
```

if document.getElementById("nosecolor").value = "#FFA6A6"

else with

```js
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: new Color("#" + document.getElementById("nosecolor").value)} );
```

if document.getElementById("nosecolor").value = "FFA6A6" (no # in the start)

**For example**, run the below snippet (inspired from a three.js [example](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene)).

```js
function createSquare() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    
    /* START - EXACT ANS */
    var a = "#"+document.getElementById("nosecolor").value;
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: (new THREE.Color(a))
    });
    /* STOP - EXACT ANS */
    
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    camera.position.z = 5;

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    animate();
}

createSquare();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nosecolor" value="FFA6A6">

<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This does not work. I need to put it in a material.

Comment: @UnityDude Please check my updated answer - it works! Try printing out `document.getElementById("nosecolor").value`, I think it's just "FFA6A6". If it is, you must use `"#" + document.getElementById("nosecolor").value` to initialize `Color`.

Comment: @UnityDude Check the updated answer. If it still doesn't work, print out the value of `document.getElementById("nosecolor").value` and add the output here.

Comment: I'm so sorry, still doesn't work for me. ```var a = "#"+document.getElementById("nosecolor").value;
 material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
  color: (new THREE.Color(a)).getHex()
 });```

Comment: @UnityDude What's `document.getElementById("nosecolor").value` (print it)?

Comment: FFA6A6 is the raw value, but I add a "#" to it

Comment: @UnityDude Just to confirm: `console.log(document.getElementById("nosecolor").value)` prints "FFA6A6" exactly? Could you add the output here, please?

Comment: @UnityDude If I read the answer right it is not saying to use `.getHex()` but instead, just use `new THREE.Color(a)` from your example. So your code would be: `var a = "#"+document.getElementById("nosecolor").value;material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: new THREE.Color(a) });`

Comment: Exact output: FFA6A6.

Comment: @UnityDude Check the updated code snippet in my answer. I added an `input` element, and now, I'm using its value (as I suggested in the answer). It clearly works! I'm not sure why it's not working for you. :)

Comment: Hey Figured it out today, wasn't positioning the new nose, thanks!

Comment: Oh, I'm glad you got it working. :) Yes, I thought something is missing when I opened your fiddle, but I couldn't debug it then.